# Can't create google chrome driver on Mac for Geb test

Tags: macos, grails, selenium-chromedriver, geb

I am using Geb to run a Grails function test.  I want to use the Chrome driver,  I follow these instructions:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

I install the google chrome driver at:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```

on my mac.

I run the test with the switch

```
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"
```

from eclipse.

When I run the test I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```

If I leave out the switch I get:

```
The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;
```

If I leave out the quotes I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /Applications/Google\
```

If I keep the quote and leave out some of the slashes

```
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

I get:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.3,platform=Mac OS X 10.8.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

First you need to install **both** the [driver](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list) and the [browser](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/). Then `webdriver.chrome.driver` system property has to point at the driver and **not the browser**.